#  slideDown on  a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do this(photoshop image) on my page:

[image]

On **hover**(over the ACTORS link) I want the yellow drop down list(where Fotis J.Colakides etc is) to show up slowly. From up  till down.

I don't know what is the best way to do this on my page.

Of course I have to use an unorder list() like this:

```
    <ul id="showInfoNav">
        <li><a class="slideBtn" href="#">MEDIA</a>
            <ul class="slideShow">
                <li>assa</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="slideBtn" href="#">ACTORS</a>
            <ul class="slideShow">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:getSummary(1)">ACTOR1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:getSummary(2)">ACTOR2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**[Update]**

Util now I have done this: (http://jsfiddle.net/bMGhC/)

[image]

But I am doing it from css. I have the  left:-9999px; and on hover I am doing it left:0px;

I want to do it slideDown. But it is not working.

here is my css:

```
ul#showInfoNav 
    {
        list-style:none;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }

    ul#showInfoNav li
    {
        float:left;
        margin-right:50px;
        position:relative;
    }

    ul#showInfoNav a.slideBtn
    {
        padding:5px;
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none; 
    }
    ul#showInfoNav ul a:hover{
        color:#898989;
    }
    /*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
    ul#showInfoNav ul
    {
        background-color:#F4F9B6;
        padding:50px 10px 10px 10px;
        list-style:none;
        left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
        position: absolute;
        top:-20px;
        /*z-index:-1;*/
    }
    ul#showInfoNav ul li
    {

        float:none;
    }
    ul#showInfoNav ul a{
        white-space:nowrap; 
    }

    ul#showInfoNav li:hover ul{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
        left:0; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
    }
```

I have also this z-index problem. If I set it -1 it is hidden behind the image too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found, I used this because I didn't want the `<ul>` to slideUp when I was navigating among his `<li>` tags.

```
    $('ul.slideShow').hide();
    $("#showInfoNav li").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul.slideShow').slideDown('fast').show();
        $(this).hover(function () {   // PARENT

        }, function () {
            $(this).parent().find("ul.slideShow").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up 
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery UI effects, specifically slide():

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into the [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) method that jQuery supplies.

See an example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2RLz/1/)**.

Similar functions would be [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and the more general, [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `.hover()`, and `.slideUp/Down()`. You can also replace `.hover` with `.toggle` in the following code, if you'd like a more 'permanent' state. The key to both is utilizing their callback functions.

HTML

```
<a href="#">Click to see a list</a>
<ul>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('ul').hide(); // doing this rather than via CSS for a fail-safe for JS
$('a').hover(function() {
    $('ul').slideDown('fast');
    }, function() {
    $('ul').slideUp('slow')
})​
```

Comment: .hide() is working, .hover() or .slideDown/Up() is not working. All my <li> tags are in code behind(literal). Does it matter? I have this js: jquery.js, jquery-1.7.2.min.js,

Comment: You may be right. I pasted the code above into a fiddle for you. It works fine there (onload, jquery 1.6.4) http://jsfiddle.net/YeYN9/

Comment: Edited my answer.. I meant to say `.toggle` not `.click`. Toggle has the callback.

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery fadeIn() you can specify the duration too.
Some simple sample would be:

1. Give the li's some id or class ( `<li id="actor1">soemthing</li>`)
2. In the JS file or script tag use:

   $("#actor1).hover(function(){ $(this).slideDown('slow')}, function(){ $(this).slideUp('slow') });

EDIT: I see that you want a sliding effect so, I changed `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` to `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`. You can read their documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=slide)